# Bob Dylan - Mixed Up Confusion

Tags: history

I have a treasured copy of Mixed Up Confusion/Corrina Corrina - the Dutch reissue from the late 60s. I always understood that the version of Mixed Up Confusion was the one that appeared on Dylan's debut US single, but some time ago I read an article that implied that it was a different take. Can anyone help, one way or the other? Many thanks.